# (XAMPP) Changing locale to English in Apache

Tags: php, apache, xampp

When I entered incorrected url:

```
    http://localhost/404url
```

the response message from server not in English:

> Objet non trouvé!
>
> L'URL demandée n'a pas pu être trouvée sur ce serveur. Si vous avez
>   tapé l'URL à la main, veuillez vérifier l'orthographe et réessayer.
>
> Si vous pensez qu'il s'agit d'une erreur du serveur, veuillez
>   contacter le webmestre.

How can I change default language to English?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to -> **xampp\apache\error** and open **HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var**, then add the following code in the file, save it and restart apache.

```
Content-language: en
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Body:----------en--
<!--#set var="TITLE" value="Object not found!"
--><!--#include virtual="include/top.html" -->

    The requested URL was not found on this server.

  <!--#if expr="-n v('HTTP_REFERER')" -->

    The link on the
    <a href="<!--#echo encoding="url" var="HTTP_REFERER" -->">referring
    page</a> seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of
    <a href="<!--#echo encoding="url" var="HTTP_REFERER" -->">that page</a>
    about the error.

  <!--#else -->

    If you entered the URL manually please check your
    spelling and try again.

  <!--#endif -->

<!--#include virtual="include/bottom.html" -->
----------en--
```

Hope, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you @ℛⱥℐℰşℎ. This code already have in  HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var file. I entered 404 url on Firefox and IE, it works fine. May be this just happen on Chorme.